# mySQL return rows containing search terms

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return all rows where some column contains all keywords. Keywords can be in **any order** and **surrounded by anything**. I've looked into FULL TEXT searches but none seem to give the kind of control I want. I can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles 
WHERE body LIKE '%term1%' AND body LIKE '%term2%' AND body LIKE '%term3'...
```

But this gets messy with an arbitrary number of search terms. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Fulltext binary search](http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/) (on that page search for A Basic Boolean Searching Application).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE MATCH (body) AGAINST
       ('term1 +term2 +term3 etc...' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

here '+[keyword]' is the equivalent of AND.  if you search a keyword in different columns, so you can; where match (col1,col2,col3 etc...) against ('keyword'). Remember, you need to define a FULLTEXT index that contains which columns will be searched (used in "match (col1,col2...)" part)

Comment: FTS treats the terms as separate words. If I search for "cat" it ignores articles containing only "cats" - this is a problem.